# Site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create facebook app with the website url http://www.odipi.com/
but it says

Error

Site URL is not a valid URL.

Also, I had checked

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.odipi.com

It says
Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

I am not sure what is the issue. Can you help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try and post your URL to Facebook, I get the following message:

> The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been
>   blocked for being spammy or unsafe:
>
> odipi.com
>
> For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're
>   seeing this by mistake, please [let us know](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal).

So it looks like your URL has been used for spam purposes in the past, thus you will need to appeal the block.